# How to save output into single drop-down with django

Tags: python, html, django

I have a scraper that scraper data on cruises, I am grabbing the title of the cruise. My aim was to output these results into a single drop down menu so I can select one of these from the drop-down. However, it instead produces multiple input options and only a single title in the drop down. I.E.

[image]

My script:

models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Cruises(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField(max_length=200)
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Cruises

def basic(request):
    long_list = Cruises.objects.values('title')
    return render(request, 'cruise_control/basic.html', context = {'long_list':long_list})
```

basic.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Cruises</title>
  </head>
<body>
<h1> Cruise Control </h1>

{% for lng_l in long_list %}
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <label for='destination'>Destination</label>
  <input type="text" list="destination" />
  <datalist id="destination">
  <option>{{lng_l.title}}</option>
  </datalist>
  <!label for="cruisetime">Departure date</label>
  <!input type="date" id="cruisetime" name="cruisetime" min={{dep_l.departureDate}}>
  <!input type="submit">
</form>
{% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly, your for loop in the template should only include the options tag. Everything else should be outside of it.

Answer (score 0):

Your class `Cruises` contains only one title. As for the loops in the template, you are looping the forms. Whereas you want one in a form with many options.

I think you should be interested in a [many-to-many](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) relationship. Then you will be able to assign multiple options to a particular object.

Also you should see [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField) about forms.